# Why does maven detects windows os as dos family?

Tags: java, windows, maven

Here is the output:

```
mvn enforcer:display-info

[INFO] Maven Version: 3.3.9
[INFO] JDK Version: 1.8.0_60 normalized as: 1.8.0-60
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: amd64 Family: dos Name: windows 7 Version: 6.1
```

OS name is `Windows 7`, but family is `dos`.

Is it a bug or maven always recognize windows family as dos?

Comment: Which version of maven-enforcer-plugin do you use?

Comment: Effective pom do not contains such informatrion, `maven-enforcer-plugin` itsefl does not contains a goal for that. Could you please tell how to see this version?

Comment: During the build there are outputs which tells you that.